# c++11 plain old object default value

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

How can I initialize a member variable of a POD (Plain Old Data) in C++11?

```
class A {
public:
    int theAnswer; // this is not initialized
};

static_assert(std::is_pod<A>::value, "A must be a plain old object");

class B {
public:
    int theAnswer { 42 }; //  this should initialize to 42
};

static_assert(std::is_pod<B>::value, "B must be a plain old object"); // ERROR

class C {
public:
    C() : theAnswer { 42 } { } // Obviously, this is not a trivial default constructor, so it does not work
    int theAnswer;
};

static_assert(std::is_pod<C>::value, "C must be a plain old object"); // ERROR
```

Comment: Nitpicky: POD stands for Plain Old Data (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do it where you initialize the whole object. A plain old data object is just that: plain old data, with no invariants, initialization, or any of that fancy stuff. If you want initialization, then it's not POD.

But maybe you don't actually need a POD. Maybe trivially copyable is enough? If all you want to do is memcpy between objects, trivially copyable is the trait you're looking for, not POD.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Trivially copyable with memcpy is good enough for my case.

Comment: Unforunately, my compiler (gcc 4.7.3) does not support std::is_trivially_copyable

Answer (score 2):

Here is some standardese explaining why you can't initialize POD members inside the class itself.

`[class]/10`:

> A *POD struct* is a non-union class that is both a **trivial class** and a standard-layout class

`[class]/6`:

> A *trivial class* is a class that has a default constructor (12.1), has **no non-trivial default constructors**, and is trivially copyable.

`[class.ctor]/4`:

> A default constructor is trivial if it is **not user-provided** and if:
>   — its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
>   — **no non-static data member of its class has a *brace-or-equal-initializer***, and
>   — all the direct base classes of its class have trivial default constructors, and
>   — for all the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial default constructor.